# Nav Menu Hover not working

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been trying really hard to get my Hover feature of my navigation menu to work but its just not changing colour, any ideas?

It works if I dont have individual classes for the different list items but I want them to be in different colours but all change to the same colour when hovering.

```
    #container .navigationContainer .navigation
{
    float: right;
    margin: 44px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation ul
{
    list-style: none;   
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.home
{
    margin: 0 0 0 26px;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    width: 156px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font: normal .75em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #369ed1;
    border-top: solid 2px #369ed1;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.home a,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.home a:link,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.home a:active,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.home a:visited
{
    color: #369ed1;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 156px;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.home a:hover
{
    color: #373431;
    border-top: solid 2px #373431;
}
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.about
{
    margin: 0 0 0 26px;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    width: 156px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font: normal .75em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #a6bb54;
    border-top: solid 2px #a6bb54;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.about a,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .about a:link,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .about a:active,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .about a:visited
{
    color: #a6bb54;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 156px;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .about a:hover
{
    color: #373431;
    border-top: solid 2px #373431;
}
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio
{
    margin: 0 0 0 26px;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    width: 156px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font: normal .75em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #df3f89;
    border-top: solid 2px #df3f89;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:link,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:active,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:visited
{
    color: #df3f89;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 156px;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:hover
{
    color: #373431;
    border-top: solid 2px #373431;
}
#container .navigationContainer .navigation .active
{
    margin: 0 0 0 26px;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    width: 156px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font: normal .75em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #373431;
    border-top: solid 2px #373431;
}

#container .navigationContainer .navigation .active a,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation .active a:link,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation .active a:active,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation .active a:visited
{
    color: #373431;
    text-decoration: none;
```

EDIT:

html code:

```
<div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code as well?

Comment: Yes post your HTML code

Comment: `li.portfolio` and `li .portfolio` (with a space) are two different things, and you are using both of them. Witch one is right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this might be what you're looking for.

I've cleaned your HTML/CSS up a little too (hope you don't mind!)

```
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-item home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LNkNL/

Take a look at the above Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the example... this worked great and helped me to understand nav bars better

Comment: @BoneStarr not a problem :) glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you're inconsistently referring to you `<a>` tags.

```
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:link,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:active,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:visited
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li .portfolio a:hover
```

Should probably be

```
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a:link,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a:active,
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a:visited
#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.portfolio a:hover
```

ie. `<li>`'s have the `portfolio` class. This would explain why hover isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write `a:hover` or `.about a:hover` instead of `#container .navigationContainer .navigation li.about a:hover`

```
a:hover
{
    color: #373431;
    border-top: solid 2px #373431;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/syHxY/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the block to `<a>` element that might work.

```
a{display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I believe in specifically *not* re-writing the code for the original poster, but rather to provide general examples and guidelines on how the desired solution might be achieved, to wit:

There are many ways to do hover behavior, perhaps the easiest being to simply implement it in CSS.

Here is a simple HTML page with a CSS style block that defines a class called `.menu-item` and specifies hover behavior for that class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        /* General body styles: */
        body {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        /* menu item class: */
        .menu-item {
            width: 180px;
            margin-left:12px;
        }
        /* menu item hover behavior: */
        .menu-item:hover {
            border-bottom: 5px;
            border-left: 0px;
            border-right: 0px;
            border-top: 0px;
            border-color: red;
            border-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--    
    Specify the menu-item class on a set of  
    span elements to comprise the menu items: 
    -->
    <span class='menu-item'>Item 1</span><span class='menu-item'>Item 2</span><span class='menu-item'>Item 3</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I used `span` elements here for the menu items, but you could just as easily define some `div` elements with `inline-block` styles.

**See a working example here:**

http://conversiondynamics.com/hovertest.html

Cheers,
-=Cameron